# Calling npx from a node.js file

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I've tried using `exec` with a bash file, I've tried using direct calls, I've tried digging into npm and npx docs but there seems to be no answer to this question: how can an npx call be triggered form node.js code?

An answer that triggers the same functionality as an npx call without actually being written as an npx call would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not really sure where your problem is...

- how you call `npx` scripts in general?
- running shell commands from within node?
- Running specifically `npx` commands? Is there an error you get?

The most widespread way to run shell commands would be `child_process`, and I don't know why you couldn't just put an `npx` command in there (I just tested it with `npx --help` and that worked):

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("echo Hello World", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error();
    console.error("Error:");
    console.error(err);
    console.error();
  }
  console.log(stdout);
  console.error(stderr);
});
```

Now, this might be what you meant by "tried using `exec`", and you just get an error doing that. Of course, it would be helpful to have that error in that case, but maybe it is that `npx` isn't found.

Make sure you have npx installed then - maybe it's just `npm`s virutal environment that can't access it, so you could use `npm install npx` to install it into there. If you are running it with `npm`, make sure it's installed globally: `npm install -g npx`.

If it is a different problem, please provide more information on what exactly you are lacking or potential errors you are getting.

Comment: I had no idea why my `child_process` couldn't call npx commands. I assumed there was some sort of magic happening under the hood I was too uninformed to understand. Your answer helped contextualise that the problem was something trivial. I've reinstalled npm and now everything works. Thank you and apologies for the poorly-formulated question.